# D3 Does not render or paint DOM element

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw the SVG elements from an array of different shapes. I can see all shapes added to the document successfully but I cannot see them rendered on the screen. Interestingly, if I just try to edit the HTML element (without making any changes) from the browser's DOM explorer (in my case Chrome) the shapes get drawn as expected. Any suggestion of what's being done wrong here?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/1qd2kt9s/

Thanks

```js
var my_data=[{"shape":"circle","attr":{"r":"50","cx":"60","cy":"60", "fill":"red"}  }
,{"shape":"rect","attr":{"width":"100","height":"100","x":"120","y":"10", "fill":"blue"}  }
            ];
var svg=d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
        .attr("width",500)
        .attr("height",500);
var shapes=svg.selectAll('.shapes')
    .data(my_data);
shapes.enter()
    .append(function(d,i) {
        return document.createElement(d.shape);
    })
        .each(function(d,i){
           d3.select(this).attr(d.attr);
        });
```

```html
Here is what I can see in the browser DOM elements list:
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <circle r="50" cx="60" cy="60" fill="red"></circle>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="120" y="10" fill="blue"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript creates elements in the HTML namespace by default, you need the SVG namespace for them to be interpreted correctly:

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', d.shape);
```

Complete demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/1qd2kt9s/1/).

Comment: Lars is without a shadow of a doubt a mega star. You are the master sir. Problem solved.