# How to overcome the disappearance of the D3JS tree if group tag id is appended

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree, append

I am trying to add an id to the first <g> tag that contains the entire tree by adding the following code

```
var gElement = document.createElement('g');
gElement.setAttribute("id", "fg");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append(function() { return gElement; })
//.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

If I replace the **.append("g")** with **.append(function() { return gElement; })** the graph disappears from the screen, although it is in the inspection panel

I used a standard tree [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671166/adding-class-to-root-node-in-d3js-tree-layout) and added the above code.

the svg content:

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
    <g id="fg" transform="translate(120,20)">
        <path class="link"
            d="M180,197.1428571428571C270,197.1428571428571 270,131.42857142857142 360,131.42857142857142"></path>
        <path class="link"
            d="M180,197.1428571428571C270,197.1428571428571 270,262.85714285714283 360,262.85714285714283"></path>
        <path class="link" d="M0,262.85714285714283C90,262.85714285714283 90,197.1428571428571 180,197.1428571428571">
        </path>
        <path class="link" d="M0,262.85714285714283C90,262.85714285714283 90,328.57142857142856 180,328.57142857142856">
        </path>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(180,328.5714416503906)">
            <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start"
                style="fill-opacity: 1;">Level 2: B</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(360,262.8571472167969)">
            <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start"
                style="fill-opacity: 1;">Daughter of A</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(360,131.42857360839844)">
            <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start"
                style="fill-opacity: 1;">Son of A</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(180,197.14285278320312)">
            <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="-13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end"
                style="fill-opacity: 1;">Level 2: A</text>
        </g>
        <g class="node" transform="translate(0,262.8571472167969)">
            <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="-13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end"
                style="fill-opacity: 1;">Top Level</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

What is causing this behavior and how can I overcome it?

Comment: You need to specify that you are creating an SVG element, not an HTML element, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288730/7106086) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064556/7106086). Pulling from these, does using `document.createElementNS` solve your issue? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999444/7106086) may also be useful.

Comment: Specifically, you need to use `var gElement = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'g');`